# How to go back to previous version of database schema.I am using hibernate as implementation of jpa

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am using hibernate as JPA implementation for creating and interacting with database.Now I get one doubt that is **lets suppose current version has some five columns in a table , In second version i want to remove one column from that table(coming back to previous version).** How can i do that using hibernate.

Comment: JPA providers do not do schema management as a general rule (or at least are not the best at that type of job). You are better off using tools like Flyway and Liquibase, so they should be the place you look initially

Comment: Thanks @Stockton , i will check those things.